# 'Return' column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database tables have a `Return` column name. Now I'm having a problem whenever I'm trying to use it as condition.
I'm also having an SQL error saying

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword '`Return`'

whenever I'm trying to do this `SELECT Return FROM My_Table`. I know I'm having that error because Return is one of the SQL syntax.

I've been searching on google, but I couldn't find the right keywords for that answer. Now, I want to know if is there any possible solution for that problem without renaming my column as it would cause a big effect on my system?

Comment: Try to access the column name like this: [Return]

Comment: It's generally a **horribly bad idea** to use any of the [SQL Server reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) for your own database objects (tables, views, column names etc.)

Comment: You need a delimited identifier since `return` is a reserved word. ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g. `"Return"`. SQL Server also supports square brackets, `[Return]`.

Comment: @marc_s I know it is a very bad idea, but I can't do anything, I wasn't the one who designed the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the column name in bracket `[Return]`.

```
select [Return] from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL you can use special characters or reserved words using [] or "".

```
SELECT 1 AS [RETURN], 2 AS "RETURN"
```

My suggestion: avoid, if possibile to use spec chars and res. words, and use plain simple names.